# Trying to get a dotted curve with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me to get the same output as in the following figure?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
% both figures
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {A,B}
{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5*\ii-5,0)}]
    \node at (-0.2,3.8) {\bfseries \i.};
    \draw[latex-latex] (0,3) node[above] {$y$-tokens} |- (3,0) node[right] {\strut$x$-tokens};
    \draw[blue] plot [domain=1/2.75:2.75,samples=101] (\x,1/\x) node[black,right] {$k$};
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,1) node[left] {$y$} -| (1,0) node[below] {\strut$x$};
    \fill (1,1) circle (0.3mm);
  \end{scope}
}
% A figure
\draw[densely dotted] (0,0.5) node[left] {$y+\Delta y$} -| (2,0) node[below] {\strut$x+\Delta x$};
\fill (2,0.5) circle (0.3mm);
% B figure
\begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}]
  \draw[blue,shift={(0.75,0.75)}] plot [domain=1/2:2,samples=101] (\x,1/\x) node[black,right] {$k_\Delta$};
  \draw[densely dotted] (0,1.75) node[left] {$y+\Delta y$} -| (1.75,0) node[below] {\strut$x+\Delta x$};
  \draw[dashed,->] (0,0) -- (2.5,2.5);
  \fill (1.75,1.75) circle (0.3mm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to make it as similar as possible to the base image. Some things didn't turn out the way I would have liked but overall it was good (I think).

### Input

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.5,
    every node/.style={scale=0.5},
    >={Triangle[scale=0.6]}
    ]

    % Drawing the main axis:
    \draw[<->]  (0,1/0.25) node[above]{$y$} -- 
                (0,0) node[below left]{0} -- 
                (4.5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    % Drawing the main function:
    \draw[thick] plot[domain=0.28:4.4, samples=200](\x,{1/\x}) node[right]{$k^{0}$};
    % Drawing the dotted lines:
    \draw[densely dotted, thick]    (1,0) node[below]{$x^{0}$} |-
                                    (0,1) node[left]{$y^{0}$};
    % Drawing the dashed lines:
    \foreach \x in {0.55,1,1.3,2}{
        \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (\x,1/\x);
    }
    % Drawing the points:
    \foreach \p in {0.45, 0.55, 1, 1.3, 2, 2.6}{
        \draw[fill=black] (\p,1/\p) circle (1pt);
    }
    % Labeling the points:
    \node[above right] (M'') at (0.45,1/0.45){$M''$};
    \node[above right] (A) at (0.55,1/0.55){$A$};
    \node[above right] at (1,1){$P$};
    \node[above right] at (1.3,1/1.3){$M$};
    \node[above right] (B) at (2,1/2){$B$};
    \node[above right] (M') at (2.6,1/2.6){$M'$};
    % Drawing the arrows:
    \draw[->] (A) -- (M'');
    \draw[->] (B) -- (M');
    \draw[->] (0.4,3.2) -- (0.55,3.2);
    \draw[->] (3.5,0.45) -- (3.65,0.45);
    % Drawing the dashed function:
    \draw[  thick, 
            xshift = 0.3cm, 
            yshift = 0.3cm, 
            dash pattern = on 10.85pt off 3pt
    ] plot[domain=0.28:4.4, samples=200](\x,{1/\x}) node[right]{$k^{1}$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, 
              label=above right:#1,
              node contents={}},
samples=101    
                        ]
% axis
\draw[latex-latex] (0,3) node[above] {$y$} |- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
% curve k0
\draw[blue, thick]
    plot [domain=1/2.75:2.75] (\x,1/\x) node[black,right] {$k^0$};
% curve k1
\draw[blue,thick, dashed, 
      transform canvas = {shift={(0.75,0.75)}}] 
      plot [domain=1/2.25:2.25] (\x,1/\x) node[black,right] {$k^1$};
% coordinate x^0, y^0
\draw[densely dotted] (0,1) node[left] {$y^0$} -| (1,0) node[below] {$x^0$};
    \fill (1,1) circle (0.3mm);

% rays
\draw[densely dashed]   (0,0) node[below left] {$O$} 
                              -- (0.75,1/0.75) node (a) [dot=$A$] 
                        (0,0) -- (1.00,1/1.00) node (p) [dot=$P$]
                        (0,0) -- (1.25,1/1.25) node (m) [dot=$M$]
                        (0,0) -- (1.75,1/1.75) node (b) [dot=$B$];
\path   (0.5,1/0.5) node (m'') [dot=$M''$]
        (2.5,1/2.5) node (m')  [dot=$M'$];
\draw[arr, transform canvas = {shift={(0.1,0.1)}}] (a) -- (m'');
\draw[arr, transform canvas = {shift={(0.1,0.1)}}] (b) -- (m');
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Purely for comparison, here is version drawn with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path xx, yy, ff, k[];
    xx = 20 left -- 300 right;
    yy = xx rotated 90;
    ff = (1, 1) {dir -45} for x = 2 upto 5: .. (x, 1/x) endfor;
    ff := reverse ff reflectedabout(origin, (1,1)) & ff;
    k0 = ff scaled 280/5; 
    k1 = subpath (2, 6) of ff scaled 280/3;

    pair A, B, P, M, M', M'';
    A = point 3 of k0;
    P = point 4 of k0;
    M = point 4.5 of k0;
    B = point 5.2 of k0;
    M' = point 6 of k0;
    M'' = point 2.1 of k0;

    draw (xpart P, 0) -- P -- (0, ypart P) dashed withdots scaled 1/4;
    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;
    draw k0 withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw k1 withcolor 2/3 red dashed evenly scaled 2;

    vardef path_alongside(expr P, t, r, s) = 
        subpath (t-r, t+r) of P shifted (s * unitvector(direction t of P rotated 90))
    enddef;

    ahangle := 30;
    drawarrow path_alongside(k0, 5.67, 0.2, 6) withcolor 1/2 blue;
    drawarrow path_alongside(k0, 2.5, -0.3, 6) withcolor 1/2 blue;

    for t = 1, 7:
        drawarrow point t of k0 -- point 1/2 t of k1
            cutbefore fullcircle scaled 12 shifted point t of k0
            cutafter  fullcircle scaled 12 shifted point 1/2 t of k1
            withcolor 1/2 red;
    endfor
    
    forsuffixes $ = A, B, P, M:
        draw origin -- $ dashed evenly withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;
    endfor
    forsuffixes $ = A, B, P, M, M', M'':
        dotlabel.urt("$" & str $ & "$", $);
    endfor
    label.lft("$y^0$", (0, ypart P));
    label.bot("$x^0$", (xpart P, 0));
    dotlabel.llft("$0$", origin);
    label.rt("$k^0$", point 8 of k0);
    label.rt("$k^1$", point 8 of k1);
    label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en), so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.